# "Exit command"(back to mainprogram) on my NDK-android thread

Tags: android, command, android-ndk, exit, native-code

I'm running a main program. I have a button to start native-activity(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html)

I am looking for a command to return back to my main program.

That is a command that does the same as when i press the back button.

So i can have the native-activity return back to the main program after X seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the **[finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish)** method to close your current activity and return to whichever other activity called it.